# как разделить бустрап секцию?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Всем привет. Сейчас верстаю сайт(только учусь), и наткунлся на проблему, нужно сделать 2 колонки вертикальные, как на макете.[[image: макет[1]]

но получается, вот такая хрень[image: хрень]

перепробовал много способов, но ничего не получается.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="provide" class="provide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="title">
          <h2 class="title_main">
            Do you know we can <br> provide for you ?
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.Lorem ni ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, ed doi eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="Learn more" class="title__btn">
          Learn more
        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="title__column">
            <i class="fas fa-cog title__icon"></i>
            <div class="tittle__block">
              <h3>
                Management
              </h3>
              <p class="title__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="title__column">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt title__icon"></i>
            <div class="tittle_block">
              <h3>
                Management
              </h3>
              <p class="title__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="title__column">
            <i class="far fa-gem title__icon"></i>
            <div class="tittle_block">
              <h3>
                Management
              </h3>
              <p class="title__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="title__column">
            <i class="fas fa-truck title__icon"></i>
            <div class="tittle_block">
              <h3>
                Management
              </h3>
              <p class="title__text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: При запуске вашего примера прямо тут все выводится, как вам и надо. Возможно что-то в ваших кастомных стилях сбивает дизайн. Добавьте ваши стили, которые используются в примере

Comment: хорошо, спасибо